# Send old Simplenews to newly registered users?

Tags: emails

I have sent a Simplenews newsletter.

Added some new users since this mailing, and would like to resend it to some newly subscribed users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality isn't built into simplenews but some of its functions can get you close:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'simplenews', 'includes/simplenews.mail');

//The node id of the newsletter to send
$nid = 123; 

//The array of emails to receive the newsletter
$users = array('user@example.com','user2@example.com'); 

simplenews_send_test(node_load($nid), $users);
```

That should send out a newsletter to all users.

The one caveat is it will be marked as a test email with Simplenews's test footer at the bottom. This can be overridden via a custom simplenews-newsletter-footer.tpl.php to remove "This is a test version of the newsletter." from the footer.

Answer (score 2):

I also found a brute way.

Set newsletter sending status to 0 which will allow a resend to the entire userbase.

Install https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_filter

Select only the users that were missed the last time via Views, and send.

(One could also select to send all and delete the subscriber ids from the spool table where you dont want to send)